# Google script: Paste the values to the last row of column A only

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

This script is intended to copy the column values of multiple rows which i highlighted/selected and paste to another googlesheet. However the column b and c of the target spreadsheet already contains formula and i want the code to ignore it and get the lastrow of the column A instead, is there a way to do it and it would not change the value/formula of column b and c ? Thank you in advance

```
function copySelectedRows() {
  var sourceSpreadsheetId = "SOURCE_SPREADSHEET_ID";
  var targetSpreadsheetId = "TARGET_SPREADSHEET_ID";
  
  var sourceSheetName = "SourceSheetName";
  var targetSheetName = "TargetSheetName"
  
  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceSpreadsheetId);
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sourceSheetName);
  
  var targetSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetSpreadsheetId);
  var targetSheet = targetSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(targetSheetName);
  
  var selection = sourceSheet.getSelection();
  var selectedRanges = selection.getActiveRangeList().getRanges();
  
  var targetData = [];
  
  selectedRanges.forEach(function (range) {
    var startRow = range.getRow();
    var numRows = range.getNumRows();
    var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(startRow, 2, numRows, 4); // Assuming column B is index 2, column C is index 3, and column D is index 4
    var sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();
    
    sourceValues.forEach(function (row) {
      targetData.push([row[0], "", "", row[1], row[2], row[3]]); // Copying values from column B, C, D to E, A, and F respectively
    });
  });
  
  var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, targetData.length, targetData[0].length); // Starting from column A (1)
  targetRange.setValues(targetData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your script, how about the following modification? In this case, I guessed that when Sheets API is used, the script might be simple. So, in this modification, Sheets API is used.

Before you test this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

And, please modify your script as follows.

#### From:

```
var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, targetData.length, targetData[0].length); // Starting from column A (1)
targetRange.setValues(targetData);
```

#### To:

```
var targetLastRow = targetSheet.getRange("A1:A" + (targetSheet.getLastRow() || 1)).getDisplayValues().findIndex(([a]) => !a);
Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({ values: targetData.map(r => r.map(c => c.toString() ? c : null)) }, targetSpreadsheetId, `'${targetSheetName}'!A${targetLastRow + 1}`, { valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" });
```

#### Note:

- From your question and your showing script, I thought that `var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceSpreadsheetId);` might be `var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();`.

#### References:

- [findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)

Comment: @JP0710 Did my answer show you the result that you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue as you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. If you have issues with my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.